# Как напечатать 3 подмассива с одинаковой суммой за данным массивом?

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Условие:

> ```
> Ограничения:
> 1 <= a[i] <= 100
> 1 <= n <= 48 - длина массива
> Пример:
> 5 - размер масива
> 1 2 3 4 5 - вводимый масив
> Вывод:
> 1 2 2 - длины массивов
> 5 - первый массив и его елемент
> 1 4 - другий массив и его елементы
> 2 3 - третий массив и его елементы
> Еще тест
> 3
> 1 2 3
> Вывод
> (-1) - знак что нельзя разделить масив на три групы с равной суммой
> ```

Вот мой плохой код на python 3:

```
n = int(input())
x = input().split()
s = 0
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    x[i] = int(x[i])
    s+=x[i]
    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    if (s % 3 == 0):
        tmp = s // 3
        x.sort()
        x.reverse()
        for i in range(3):
            y = []
            j = 0
            while (sum(y) != tmp):
                if j==len(x):
                    print(-1)
                    exit()
                if ((sum(y) + x[j]) <= tmp):
                    y.append(x[j])
                    del(x[j])
                else: j += 1
    if i==0:a = y
    if i==1:b = y
    else:c = y
    print(len(a),len(b),len(c))
    s = ""
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        s+=str(a[i])+" "
    print(s)
    s = ""
    for i in range(0,len(b)):
        s+=str(b[i])+" "
    print(s)
    s = ""
    for i in range(0,len(c)):
        s+=str(c[i])+" "
    print(s)
else:
    print(-1)
```

Если кому не лень можете проверить код на наличие ошибок или его как то доработать я буду благодарен!

Comment: Опишите более подробные условия задачи

Comment: Такое описание норм?

Comment: при ввводе массива `4 1 2 3`, какой должен быть результат?

Comment: (-1) потому что (4+1+2+3)/3 = (int) 3.3, а суму 3 можно составить только 2ма способами  - (1й - 1+2, 2й - 3). Нам нужно чтобы массив можно было разделить на ровно три групы с равной суммой.Если еще не понятно то объясню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вариант:

С помощью динамического программирования собираем все возможные битовые маски, соответствующие сумме в треть общей.

Далее проверяем на наличие трёх непересекающихся масок, и  выводим соответствующие комбинации

**Edit:**
Проверил :
Первый этап - 250000 итераций и наращивание списков. Придумал тест, на котором именно этот этап тормозит, создавая 650000 подмножеств с нужной суммой `[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,11,13,19,22,23,26,27,29,31,32,37,38,41,43,49,53,67,71,94,112,153,170]`

Второй этап - кубический от числа подмножеств с суммой s/3. Если таких подмножеств много, скорость будет плоховата. Значит, нужно придумать, как упорядочить бинарные маски, чтобы быстро искать три непересекающиеся по битам маски. Можно попробовать сделать partition по части битов.

P.S. В тесте на Delphi первый этап выполняется 1700 мс, второй 1 мс. Основное время - на выделение памяти под списки (частично я их развернул заранее, но точное количество комбинаций заранее неизвестно, под все памяти не хватит)

Недостаток - при наличии в исходном массиве дубликатов и необходимости вывода всех вариантов (вопрос это не оговаривает) комбинации могут повторяться (например, для [1,1,1,1,1,1]), но это можно отфильтровать.

```
def sum3(lst):
    res = []
    s = sum(lst)
    if s % 3:
        return - 1
    ss = s //3
    dt = [[] for i in range(ss + 1)]
    dt[0] = [0]
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        for v  in range(ss, item - 1, -1):
            prev = dt[v - item]
            if len(prev) > 0:
                for x in prev:
                    dt[v].append(x | (1<<i))

    l = dt[ss]
    for i in range(len(l) - 2):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(l) - 1):
            if (l[i] & l[j] == 0):
                for k in range(j + 1, len(l)):
                    if (l[i] & l[k] == 0) and (l[j] & l[k] == 0):
                        t = []
                        t.append("+".join([str(lst[p]) for p in range(len(lst)) if ((1<<p) & l[i]) > 0]))
                        t.append("+".join([str(lst[p]) for p in range(len(lst)) if ((1<<p) & l[j]) > 0]))
                        t.append("+".join([str(lst[p]) for p in range(len(lst)) if ((1<<p) & l[k]) > 0]))
                        res.append(t)
    return res if len(res) > 0 else -1

print(sum3([1,2,3,4,5]))
[['2+3', '1+4', '5']]

print(sum3([1,2,3,4,5,7,8,11,13]))
[['1+2+3+4+8', '7+11', '5 13'], ['2+3+5+8', '7+11', '1 4 13'], 
 ['1+4+5+8', '7+11', '2 3 13'], ['1+2+7+8', '3+4+11', '5 13'], 
 ['3+7+8', '1+2+4+11', '5 13'], ['3+7+8', '2+5+11', '1 4 13']]
```

Comment: Для массива длиной 5 и с элементами 1 1 1 1 1 - должно повернуть (-1) или для масива длиной 5 и с елементами 1 2 3 5 5 - должно также повернуть (-1).Что изменить,я просто не совсем понимаю.

Comment: Для таких списков -1 возвращается в самом начале, так и было.  Для случаев вроде  [1,2,4,8], где сумма делится на 3, но составить три равных нельзя - я сейчас изменил последний return

Comment: Благодарю,вы мне очень помогли)

Comment: Блин....Ваше решение очень хорошое но идёт все же лимит(

Comment: Нужно одно решение вернуть? Если да, то остановка делается вместо `res.append(t)`  ?

Comment: Да нужно,но я так и сделал мне нужно всего лишь 1 решение я просто так сразу же выходил.

Comment: Добавил раздумья в ответ.

Comment: Памяти кстати там 512 Мб что есть очень много

Comment: На указанном примере память примерно так и потребляется, но длина этого массива всего 29. Видимо, хранилище подразумевается, но какое-то более оптимальное.

Answer (score 0):

попробую накатать несложный рекурсивный алгоритм. Идея будет в том, чтобы завести массив флагов, где будут учитываться какие элементы участвуют в результате, а какие нет.

Основная функция будет подготавливать все, что нужно, вызывать вспомогательную функцию и проверять результат:

```
List<List<int>> getThreeGroups(int[] data, int target)
{   
    var ret = new List<List<int>>();
    getThreeGroups(data, target, 0, new bool[data.Length], ret, data.Sum());
    if (ret.Count == 3)
        return ret;
    return null;
}
```

Вспомогательная функция выполняется рекурсивно. Каждую итерацию рекурсии мы либо используем текущий элемент, либо нет. Таким образом, рекурсивных вызовов будет 2^n. По сути просто перебор всех комбинаций, пока не найдем как минимум 3 результата

```
void getThreeGroups(int[] data, int target, int currInd, bool[] used, List<List<int>> ret, int restSum)
{
    if (ret.Count >= 3) return; 
    if (target == 0)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < used.Length; i++)
            if (used[i]) list.Add(data[i]);
        ret.Add(list);
        return;
    }
    if (target < 0) return;
    if (target > restSum) return ;

    if (currInd >= data.Length) return;
    int currentItem = data[currInd];

    used[currInd] = true;
    getThreeGroups(data, target - currentItem, currInd + 1, used, ret, restSum - currentItem);
    used[currInd] = false;
    if (ret.Count >= 3) return;
    getThreeGroups(data, target, currInd + 1, used, ret, restSum - currentItem);
}
```

Выводить на консоль результаты будем вот так

```
void PrintRet(List<List<int>> ret)
{
    Console.WriteLine("--- test result --");
    if (ret != null)
        foreach (var l in ret)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", l));
    else Console.WriteLine("-1");
}
```

Пара тестов

```
PrintRet(getThreeGroups(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 5));
PrintRet(getThreeGroups(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 3));
```

Вывод

```
--- test result --
1,4
2,3
5
--- test result --
-1
```

---

Код для вывода длины списка результата

```
void PrintLength(List<List<int>> ret)
{
    Console.WriteLine("--- test result --");
    if (ret != null)
        foreach (var l in ret)
            Console.WriteLine(l.Count);
    else Console.WriteLine("-1");
}
```

Проверка

```
PrintLength(getThreeGroups(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 5));
PrintLength(getThreeGroups(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 3));
```

Результат

```
--- test result --
2
2
1
--- test result --
-1
```

Comment: Хорошое предложение но длина массива равно 45 а 2^45 = 35184372088832 что по лимиту 1 секунда не зайдёт.

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets 2^45 - это худший случай, который навряд ли встретится. Вы попробуйте сначала использовать этот алгоритм, если будет TLE , то тогда надо думать про более продвинутое DP решение

Comment: У меня уже на 6-том тесте он встретился так как полным перебором я уже пользовался.

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets ну это не совсем полный перебор, так как я таки обрываю перебор если дальше смотреть смысла не имеет. То есть для полного перебора 45 чисел надо будет, чтобы искомое число было больше или равно их сумме, а это, при желании, можно проверить заранее

Comment: (https://ideone.com/dANhsS) вот ссылка на код на С++, тот который полный перебор)

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets у меня нет туда доступа, потому просто проверьте сами алгоритм - если подойдет - хорошо, не подойдет - ну ок. Просто у меня впечатление, что вы даже не проверили мое решение, а просто отмели, то есть по сути я зря писал его, что не есть хорошо :)

Comment: Прикол в том что я не пишу на С# и мне не очень понятно если сложность алгоритма 2^n то зачем проверять что оно зайдёт если на 1 секунду можно зделать максимум 10^9 операций

Comment: (https://ideone.com/HmHeLI) а так видно?

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets у меня рабочий фаервол режет почти все сайты, я даже тут картинки не вижу, потому то, что вы мне скидывете у меня не откроется. Я не в курсе местных тесткейсов, но раз вы считаете, что не пройдет, то ок

Comment: Если знаете C++ то если перекладете то может если и зайдёт то я забиру слова назад и еще и пометку зделаю :)

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets обновил ответ, добавил немного эвристики. С++ не помню уже, к сожалению )

Comment: Я вас понимаю,а можете хотя бы вивести длины масивов я попробую запустить на тестувалку и скажу вам итог)

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets обновил ответ. Хотя сам уже нашел пример, где мой алгоритм будет тупить :)

Comment: Ну все таки мне жаль что никто не смог помочь а так старались :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё вариант.

Довольно просто и работает быстро.

Вероятно, могут быть патологические случаи. Например, до того, как я стал сортировать, большой элемент в начале массива мог привести к созданию огромного дерева решений, словаря в миллионы веток и тормозам.

Смысл такой: заготовили три подмножества с исходными суммами s/3, и пробуем поставить очередной элемент в один из трёх наборов, и смотрим, удастся ли рекурсивно решить до конца.

Если получилось разобрать все суммы подмножеств на элементы, они становятся нулевыми - удача. Тогда при раскрутке рекурсии регистрируем, какой элемент был приписан к какому подмножеству.

В таком виде алгоритм экспоненциальный, поэтому использована мемоизация (top-down ДП) по ключу - совокупность оставшихся сумм подмножеств + номер обрабатываемого элемента.  При отладке я делал строковый ключ, потом для экономии и скорости всё это упаковал в Int64.

Код на Delphi.

```
function Solve3(A: TArray<Integer>): string;
var
  Map: TDictionary<Int64, boolean>;
  //Map: TDictionary<string, boolean>;
  Lists: array of TStringList;
  found: Boolean;

function CheckSubsetsWithItem(Subs: TArray<Word>; idx: Int16): boolean;
var
  key: Int64;
//  key: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
    if (Subs[0] or Subs[1] or Subs[2]) = 0 then begin
      found:= True;
      Exit(True);
    end;

    if idx < 0 then
       Exit(False);    

    key := 0;
    Move(Subs[0], key, 3 * SizeOf(Word));
    key := key or (idx shl 24);

   //  отладочный map содержит текущие суммы в явном виде
   //  key := Format('%d_%d_%d_%d', [subs[0], subs[1], subs[2], idx]);

    if  Map.ContainsKey(key) then
       //мемоизация
       Result := Map.Items[key]
    else begin
        Result := false;
        //пробуем засунуть A[idx] в первый, второй или третий субсет
        for i := 0 to 2 do begin
           if Subs[i] >= A[idx] then begin
            Subs[i] := Subs[i] - A[idx];
            Result := CheckSubsetsWithItem(Subs, idx - 1);
            if Result  then begin
              //восстанавливаем сами субсеты на обратном ходу
              if found then
                 Lists[i].Add(A[idx].ToString);
              break;
            end
            else
              //крови попилО это место ;)
              //надо же восстановить суммы перед следующей пробой
              Subs[i] := Subs[i] + A[idx];
           end;
        end;
        //записали результат на будущее - мемоизация
        Map.add(key, Result);
    end;
end;


var
  n, sum, s3: Integer;
  Subs: TArray<Word>;
begin
  n := Length(A);
  sum := SumInt(A);
  if sum mod 3 <> 0 then
    Exit('Сумма не кратна 3');
  s3 := sum div 3;
  found := False;

  //иначе долго ищет, если больщие числа стоят в начале
  TArray.Sort<Integer>(A);

  Map := TDictionary<Int64, boolean>.Create;
//  Map := TDictionary<string, boolean>.Create;
  SetLength(Lists, 3);
  Lists[0] := TStringList.Create;
  Lists[1] := TStringList.Create;
  Lists[2] := TStringList.Create;

   if CheckSubsetsWithItem([s3, s3, s3], n - 1) then begin
     Result := '[' + Lists[0].CommaText + '], ' +
               '[' + Lists[1].CommaText + '], ' +
               '[' + Lists[2].CommaText + ']';
   end else
     Result := 'Noooo :(';
end;



 Memo1.Lines.Add(Solve3([1, 5, 4, 3, 2]));
 Memo1.Lines.Add(Solve3([1, 153, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 913, 19, 22, 23,
                 26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37, 38, 41, 43, 49, 53, 67,
                 71, 94, 112, 170, 189, 211, 47, 61, 97, 16, 3, 51,
                144, 402, 231, 289, 256, 297, 303, 324, 361, 441, 225, 195]));

[5], [1,4], [2,3]

[2,16,303,402,441,913], 
[94,225,231,256,289,297,324,361], 
[1,3,4,5,7,8,11,19,22,23,26,27,29,31,32,37,38,41,43,47,49,51,53,
 61,67,71,97,112,144,153,170,189,195,211]
```

Comment: Все хорошо но я паскаль знаю а делфи нет((((

Comment: В дельфи язык - паскаль. Да и вообще большинство процедурных языков без синтаксического сахара одинаковы. Оно легко переведётся на питон,  с++, шарп или джаву, там с map только поудобнее будет, и от вложенной функции придётся избавиться (мне она позволяет не передавать массив в аргументах). Кроме того, я всё описал текстом.

Answer (score -1):

```
  Ввели a;
  Ввели массив[] arr;
  Цикл (i от 1 до (int)a/2)
  {  
     Если (i не содержится в arr) переходим на следующую итерацию;
     Вывести: i  (a-i);
  }
```

Comment: Что это? Вы на какой вопрос отвечаете?

Comment: @MBo и что не так?

Comment: Этот ответ не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу об одинаковых суммах.

Comment: @MBo подумал что то рандомной числа))) ну тогда от автора нужно пару разъяснений (например за ограничения не понятно, и что такое {1 2 3 4 5 } + то, что он пытался сделать!!!

Comment: @MBo первое число разложить которое надо, а массив - числа, использующиеся в сумме?

Comment: я брал вообще суму искал делил на 3 и старался набрать такую суму елементов,и сразу же их удалял но у меня неверный ответ(

Comment: Нужно пройтись по числам от 1 до вводимого/2(округлить в меньшую сторону) и получится первое число = значение текущей итерации, второе число = вводимое - значение текущей итерации.