# Помогите найти решение задачи на java

Tags: java

Имеется  следующая задача:

В спортивном зале города N появилась штанга и набор блинов с различными массами.
Для занятия спортом необходимо распределить блины по двум концам штанги таким
образом, чтобы суммарный вес по оба конца штанги был одинаковый. Рассчитайте
максимальный вес, который смогут поднимать спортсмены при заданном наборе блинов
(с допущением, что гриф штанги невесомый).

Решение должно быть представлено в виде java-программы, у которой:

На входе: массив целых чисел, обозначающих веса блинов, входящих в набор.
На выходе: целое число, обозначающее максимальный вес, который можно поднять с
заданным набором блинов.

Примеры:

1. - На входе: `[1,2,3,6]`
   - На выходе: `12`
   - Пояснение: можно нацепить блины `{1,2,3}` с одной стороны и блин `{6}` с другой, что в сумме даст `12`.
2. - На входе: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
   - На выходе: `20`
   - Пояснение: можно нацепить блины `{2,3,5}` с одной стороны и блины `{4,6}` с другой, что в сумме даст `20`. Оставшийся блин `{1}` не может быть нацеплен ни с одной из сторон без потери равновесия.
3. - На входе: `[1,2]`
   - На выходе: `0`
   - Пояснение: данный набор блинов невозможно нацепить без потери равновесия.

Ограничения:

1. Блин может весить от `0` до `20` фунтов.
2. В наборе может присутствовать от `1` до `1000` блинов.
3. Суммарный вес целого набора не может превышать `10000` фунтов.

Сейчас учусь java и решаю задачи. Никак не могу найти подход к данной задачи. Помогите пожалуйста решить, или направьте мысль в нужное русло.

Comment: Зачем закрыли? Хорошая же задача. Я еще одно решение придумал.

Answer (score 3):

Например так

```
    List<Integer> weights = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 6);

    int size = weights.stream()
            .mapToInt(x -> x)
            .sum() / 2 + 1;

    int[] arr = new int[size];
    arr[0] = 2;
    for (int weight : weights) {

        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i] > 0 && i + weight < size) {
                arr[i + weight]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] >= 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Я все таки домучал. Решение получилось почти в лоб. Оно строит все возможные способы получить все возможные суммы. Затем находит наибольшую сумму у которой есть два не пересекающихся разложения.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<W> weights = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9)
                .map(W::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Map<Integer, List<List<W>>> arr = new HashMap<>();
        arr.put(0, Collections.singletonList(Collections.emptyList()));
        for (W weight : weights) {
            arr = arr.entrySet().stream()
                    .flatMap(x -> {
                                int newWeight = x.getKey() + weight.value;
                                List<List<W>> newList = x.getValue().stream()
                                        .map(ArrayList::new)
                                        .peek(y -> y.add(weight))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                                return Stream.of(
                                        new Pair<>(newWeight, newList),
                                        new Pair<>(x.getKey(), x.getValue())
                                );
                            }
                    )
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Pair::getIndex,
                            Pair::getValue,
                            (x, y) -> {
                                List<List<W>> r = new ArrayList<>(x);
                                r.addAll(y);
                                return r;
                            }));
        }

        arr.entrySet().
                stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .filter(x ->
                {
                    for (List<W> a : x.getValue()) {
                        for (List<W> b : x.getValue()) {
                            if(a == b) continue;
                            if (a.stream().noneMatch(b::contains)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }

    @Data
    static class Pair<T> {
        private final int index;
        public final T value;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    static class W {
        public final int value;
    }
}
```

Класс `W` нужен чтобы различать блины с одинаковыми весами.

Comment: Вы уверены, что решение не посчитает пересекающихся субсетов? Пример `{2,2,2,3,3,5} => arr[8]==2`, однако фигвам

Comment: Посчитает. Нужно править.

Comment: Поправил. Теперь должно работать для всех случаев.

Comment: Возможно, мемоизация поможет, как [там в альтернативном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/893815/291659). Только в той задаче цель - три равные суммы, а здесь две равные + как можно меньший довесок

Comment: Я паскаль читаю с трудом, поэтому не разобрался. Но судя по описанию там используется совсем другой подход. В моем случае я и так использую кучу памяти храня все возможные комбинации для всех возможных сумм.